# Adding slides to Swipe.JS after initialization?

Tags: javascript

It's a great carousel script for mobile. Has anyone found a way to add slides to the carousel after initialization? My goal is to add more items when the user gets to the last slide (something like a 'infinite carousel').

Here is a code example:

```
this.collection.each(function(pic){
    var slide = new PictureSlideView({model:pic});
    this.$('.slide-container').append(slide.el);
},this);

this.$('.swipe').Swipe({
    continuous: false
});

// this doesn't work:
var newModel = new Picture({...});
var newSlide = new PictureSlideView({model:newModel});
this.$('.slide-container').append(slide.el);

// insert awesome code to fix it here:
// ...
```

Comment: Could you please provide a jsfiddle and a link to the carousel script?

Comment: It's difficult to reproduce my setup in a jsfiddle: i am using phonegap & backbone. Here is the script link: http://swipejs.com/.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Checking the script source i discovered calling the `setup` function after adding the new elements works:

My code now looks something like:

```
this.collection.each(function(pic){
    var slide = new PictureSlideView({model:pic});
    this.$('.slide-container').append(slide.el);
},this);

this.carousel = new Swipe(this.el.getElementsByClassName('swipe')[0], {
    continuous: false
});

// append new slide
var newModel = new Picture({...});
var newSlide = new PictureSlideView({model:newModel});
this.$('.slide-container').append(slide.el);

// run the setup again
this.carousel.setup();
```

Comment: It now seems obvious but, it would have been easier if they mentioned this in the docs: https://github.com/bradbirdsall/Swipe